# Backbone resets file upload element

Tags: backbone.js

I have an input of type=file in my Backbone view, which is not associated to any property in my Backbone model. When I choose a file, there is something in Backbone clearing it, but I cannot find what (I handle the element's change event, and the element receives the value of the chosen file, but it is then cleared). I was wondering if I should handle the view rendering somehow. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Hmm so you are capturing the change event of that file input but it is not bound to your model?  What are you doing when the file input triggers a change?

Comment: I just did $("input.class-name").change() { alert("Changed!") }; in the view initialization for testing purposes, thank you!

Comment: Can you put it in a fiddle?  I just worked on file upload recently with backbone so I might be some help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It turned out that another jQuery plugin was in the way. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the jQuery upload plugin got in the middle. It was uploading files automatically when selected in the file input, and thus clearing the field. It was not Backbone. Thank you.